# the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am following a web scraping tutorial to learn web scraping now. I followed the instructions step by step, but an error came up.

the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'

I searched this error and most of the solutions were encoding or decoding, however it didn't work for my code. When I used encoding or decoding, it gave me another error that "'dict' object has no attribute 'decode'"

I am using Python 2.7.10 on pycharm.

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/junjielin/PycharmProjects/meituan/index.py", line 46, in <module>
    main(url)
  File "/Users/junjielin/PycharmProjects/meituan/index.py", line 42, in main
    shop_id_list = get_detail_id(category_url, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/junjielin/PycharmProjects/meituan/index.py", line 35, in get_detail_id
     return json.loads(content_id.get('data')).get('poiidList')
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    'not {!r}'.format(s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'
```

And the followings is my code:

```
# —*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #解析网页，获取标签内容
import json
import lxml


url = 'http://taishan.meituan.com/'
headers = {
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4',
    'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Host':'taishan.meituan.com',
    'Referer':'http://taishan.meituan.com/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type':'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
}

def get_start_links(url):
    html = requests.get(url).text
    #print (html)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    links = [link.find('div').find('div').find('dl').find('dt').find('a')['href'] for link in soup.find_all('div', class_='J-nav-item')]
    #print (links)
    return links

def get_detail_id(url, headers=None):
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    # loads将json转dict
    content_id = json.loads(soup.find('div',class_='J-scrollloader cf J-hub')['data-async-params'])
#    a = content_id.get('data')
    return json.loads(content_id.get('data')).get('poiidList')

def main(url):
     start_url_list = get_start_links(url)
     for j in start_url_list:
         for i in  range(1, 11):
            category_url = j+'／all/page{}'.format(i)
            shop_id_list = get_detail_id(category_url, headers=headers)
            print (shop_id_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(url)
```

### Edit

Thank you for your quick responses. With your information, I removed the call to json.loads in the return statement, which became:

```
return content_id.get('data').get('poiidList')
```

However, it gave me a new error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/junjielin/PycharmProjects/meituan/index.py", line 46, in <module>
    main(url)
  File "/Users/junjielin/PycharmProjects/meituan/index.py", line 42, in main
    shop_id_list = get_detail_id(category_url, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/junjielin/PycharmProjects/meituan/index.py", line 35, in get_detail_id
    return content_id.get('data').get('poiidList')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I don't understand what this means.

Comment: Apparently `content_id.get('data')` is a dict. You're passing `content_id.get('data')` to `json.loads`. But you can't pass a dict to `json.loads`. `json.loads` only accepts strings or bytes or bytearrays.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure you just need to remove the call to `json.loads` in your `return` statement

Comment: You are trying to treat data you loaded from a JSON document as another JSON document. Don't do that unless you are certain that there is a nested encoding going on.

Comment: That's a pretty weird `／` slash you have there (in the `category_url = j+ ...` line).

Comment: Ah, indeed, it looks like you have a mix of pages. And the first one I tried does indeed nest JSON documents, so loading there is appropriate. But perhaps that's not true for *all* your pages?

Comment: Thank you for your responses.They are helpful and i already fixed the slash. I guess that should be true for all the pages...

Comment: So test if `content_id.get('data')` is a dictionary (or None, if missing entirely) and treat it appropriately.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, I actually don't know how I can test if it's a dictionary...

Comment: Could you show me how to test it? Thanks

Comment: `type(content_id.get('data')) is dict`

Comment: Are you asking about the old error or the new error? I think it's a little confusing to have all this information about multiple errors in the question. It would help if you could trim it down to the specific problem you're having.

Comment: I think solving the old error would be more meaningful